# In JSP, what do the path and value attribute do within the input tag, and how does the form prefix affect them?

Tags: java, jsp, attributes, input

Just wanted a clear answer for a direct question -- google results have been all over the place or don't address the combos you'll see below.

I'm generally a JSP newbie and have been screwing around with the following code.

```
<form:input id="theId" path="path.copied.directly.fromSomewhereElse"
    cssClass="contentTextInput" cssStyle="width: 229px" />
```

When I put that into my JSP page and load my website, it works fine and looks as my cssClass defines it.  Then I start messing with it because I want it to display a default **value**.

```
<form:input id="theId" path="path.copied.directly.fromSomewhereElse"
    value="blah" cssClass="contentTextInput" cssStyle="width: 229px" />
```

Suddenly, HTTP 500, an org.apache.jasper.JasperException!  So I decide to **remove the path** altogether, while leaving in the value.  This is just step 1 in something I know works because of prior experience.  The code is now:

```
<form:input id="theId" value="someClass.valueIWantAsDefault" 
    cssClass="contentTextInput" cssStyle="width: 229px" />
```

That actually throws an exception, too -- but then I remove the form prefix and it works-- mostly.  You see, the cssClass's effects are now gone; it looks like a regular, unaffected input textbox.  Here's the code so far.

```
<input id="theId" value="someClass.valueIWantAsDefault" 
    cssClass="contentTextInput" cssStyle="width: 229px" />
```

What exactly do these attributes (and prefix) do that makes this mix-and-match work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm guessing you're dealing with a jsp page that relies on a JSP custom tag library that's part of the Spring Framework. Here are the docs for the [`<form:input>` tag](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/spring-form.tld.html#spring-form.tld.input). `value` is not a valid attribute for this custom tag as you can see in the docs link I provided above. When you remove the `form:`, you're turning the tag into a plain old HTML `<input>` tag which is why your error is going away at that point. It's also why your css stops working. `cssClass` is not the correct attribute for the HTML `<input>` tag. It's simply `class`. They called it `cssClass` in the jsp custom tag lib most likely to avoid a lower level collision with the `Object.getClass()` method (long story, just take my word for it).